# How to pass references to init method of object in a nib?

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a UIView subclass which currently assembles itself completely programatically. It has a custom initWithFrame:bundle: initializer which is necessary because it uses the bundle passed in to load image resources.

I want to make this view a subview in a larger nib file, but then initWithCoder will be called when the nib loading code gets to it instead of my custom initializer. Is there any way I can place this view in a nib and still have my custom initialization occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can override `initWithCoder:` too if your bundle is known ahead of time (read: You don't need it passed in as a parameter). Otherwise, nope.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not known ahead of time, so I guess I'm stuck with the programmatic approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait until `awakeFromNib`, you can do your initialization in there. You still have the problem of not being able to pass the bundle into the method, though. Since `awakeFromNib` is called after initialization and setup of all outlets and actions, it might be too late for you. Maybe it's better to redesign around the nib-loading system anyway?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007486-CH1-BABGDAEF

Comment: `-awakeFromNib` is available on iOS since 2.0: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/

Comment: @Nathan, haha, you beat me to it by less than one minute!